# how can i remove href link from the image obtained by the_content() function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a photographic portfolio site.when image on single.php page is clicked the_content() function is called and user is redirected to the actual directory of the image
eg; http://www.abcxyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/311565_33735319633456038_270235255_n.jpg

I want users to be redirected to next/other post on image click, and 'm not getting the anchor tag in core wordpress files that i need to change, can anyone help?

Comment: use anchor tag `<a href="post/link"><img src="img/link"></a>`

Comment: its just like the_content() function bringing all the things. i cant find the source..if u know, then just tell me the location where i need to change anchor tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I wanted to do this WordPress style and not hack it with jQuery. So here's what you can use in your functions.php. I think it should do what you're looking to do:

```
function my_the_content_filter() {
$content = get_the_content();
$nextpost = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false));

$body = preg_replace("{<img\\s*(.*?)src=('.*?'|\".*?\"|[^\\s]+)(.*?)\\s*/?>}ims", '<a href='.$nextpost.'><img $1src=$2 $3/></a>', $content);    

return $body;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

So the function my_the_content_filter grabs the post's content and the next post's link. Uses regex to replace the hrefs wrapped around images in the content with the link to the next post. Then you add the filter to the_content function.

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

First off I think what you're doing might be a bit hacky and you probably know this so I'm going to suggest an idea.

You can retrieve the next post url with [get_next_posts_link();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link)

You can attach that to a data attribute on a relevant element that wraps that post. Say the post is wrapped a div or article tag you can add a data-nextpostlink attribute to it.

So then you could use jQuery to find images in the post quite easily rewrite the link with the next post link that you can grab from the data-nextpostlink attribute.

As I said it's hacky and in no way ideal. But if you want to do it then you can try something like this.

Another idea that would probably be better practice in WordPress terms is to use add_filter and alter the function. You'd probably need to use some regex to identify images in the_content function.